# Selenium WebDriver - How to Holds down the RIGHT mouse button?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, right-click

Using Selenium 2.0 WebDriver (java), I need to test some navigation (rotate, pan...)

I need to be able to Holds down the RIGHT button while moving the mouse.

Similarly, I need to be able to holds down the MIDDLE button while moving the mouse.

It seems to be possible only with the LEFT button.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.clickAndHold().perform();
```

Following question, i'm not dealing with any menu, button, widget but with a 3D Environment like GoogleMap where I need to simulate pan, rotate and zoom using MIDDLE button, RIGHT button and even Mouse wheel...

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use robot class to perform same.
For Right click use Button3 and for middle use Button2

Code for Right click

```
Robot robot=new Robot();
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
```

Code for Middle Button

```
Robot robot=new Robot();
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK);
```

Comment: Robot is evil but when nothing else works ... using this solution, shame for Selenium API.

Answer (score 0):

If its not a browser or windows menu ,If its a something like a web context menu you can use following code its in c# java must be similar

```
Actions actions = new Actions(WebDriver);
actions.ContextClick(webElement)
                                               .SendKeys(Keys.Down)
                                               .SendKeys(Keys.Down)
                                               .Build()
                                               .Perform();
```

you can use a combination of `actions.ClickAndHold()` and `actions.MoveToElement()` to create a drag effect , I use these to move portal widgets

Please tell me what type of menu you are working on

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not working on any menu, widget or button. I'm working on a 3D environment view like googleMap, I need to simulate pan, rotate and zoom using Mouse Right and Middle button.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.   contextClick() sends both a mouse down and mouse up.   OP is asking for just mouse-down.   It seems that this functionality does not exist and you have to use the Mouse class directly.